# Value check during iteration of a loop

Tags: javascript

So I've been sent a technical test for a job interview, I've done the vast majority of it but having an issue with one part. Effectively, it needs to check whether the health of the elephant is under 70, if it is it can no longer walk, if this is still the case on the next iteration of the interval, it needs to pronounce them dead. My code works some of the time but also allows them to go straight from healthy to dead and it also seemingly allows them to not die when the iteration happens when they can't walk.

Below is the code and a JS fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Stackz18/dprk1fto/3/

```
var timer = 0;
var monkeyArray = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
var giraffeArray = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
var elephantArray = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];

function feedingMonkeys() {
for (let i = 0; i < monkeyArray.length; i++) { //loop through array 
    var feedingNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 10); //create unique random number between 10 and 25

    if (monkeyArray[i] <= 100 && monkeyArray[i] >= 30) { // if between 99 and 30 run the code
        monkeyArray[i] = monkeyArray[i] + feedingNumber; // add random number to array value

        let TransformedArray = monkeyArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 29 ? 'Dead' : item); //remap array in new array to show status of animal
        $('.m-health').each(function (i, obj) {
            this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i]; // change html value to the new mapped array values
        });
    }

    else if (monkeyArray[i] >= 100) {
        monkeyArray[i] = 100;
    }
}}

function feedingGiraffes() {
for (let i = 0; i < giraffeArray.length; i++) { //loop through array 
    var feedingNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 10); //create unique random number between 10 and 25

    if (giraffeArray[i] <= 100 && giraffeArray[i] >= 30) { // if between 99 and 30 run the code
        giraffeArray[i] = giraffeArray[i] + feedingNumber; // add random number to array value

        let TransformedArray = giraffeArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 29 ? 'Dead' : item);  //remap array in new array to show status of animal
        $('.g-health').each(function (i, obj) {
            this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i]; // change html value to the new mapped array values
        });
    }

    else if (giraffeArray[i] >= 100) {
        giraffeArray[i] = 100;
    }
}}

function feedingElephants() {
for (let i = 0; i < elephantArray.length; i++) { //loop through array
    var feedingNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 10); //create unique random number between 10 and 25

    if (elephantArray[i] <= 100) { // if under 100 run the code 
        elephantArray[i] = elephantArray[i] + feedingNumber;

        let TransformedArray = elephantArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 70 ? item + ': Can no longer walk' : item);
        console.log(TransformedArray);

        $('.e-health').each(function (i, obj) {
            this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i];
        });

        if (elephantArray[i] > 70) {
            $(this).parents(".elephant").removeClass("walk");
        }
    }

    else if (elephantArray[i] >= 100) {
        elephantArray[i] = 100;
    }
}
}

function feeding() {
feedingMonkeys();
feedingGiraffes();
feedingElephants();}

function monkeyHealth() {
for (let i = 0; i < monkeyArray.length; i++) {
    var removeNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 21));
    monkeyArray[i] = monkeyArray[i] - removeNumber;
}

let TransformedArray = monkeyArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 29 ? 'Dead' : item);
$('.m-health').each(function (i, obj) {
    this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i];
    if (monkeyArray[i] < 30) {
        $(this).parents(".monkey").addClass("dead");
    }
});}

function giraffeHealth() {
for (let i = 0; i < giraffeArray.length; i++) {
    var removeNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 21));
    giraffeArray[i] = giraffeArray[i] - removeNumber;
}

let TransformedArray = giraffeArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 29 ? 'Dead' : item);
$('.g-health').each(function (i, obj) {
    this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i];
    if (giraffeArray[i] < 30) {
        $(this).parents(".giraffe").addClass("dead");
    }
});}

function elephantHealth() {
for (let i = 0; i < elephantArray.length; i++) {
    if (elephantArray[i] <= 70) {
        let TransformedArray = elephantArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 70 ? 'Dead' : item);
        $('.e-health').each(function (i, obj) {
            this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i];
            if (elephantArray[i] < 70) {
                $(this).parents(".elephant").removeClass("walk");
                $(this).parents(".elephant").addClass("dead");
            }
        });
    }

    else {
        let TransformedArray = elephantArray.map(item => item >= 100 ? 100 : item <= 70 ? item + '%: Can no longer walk': item);
        $('.e-health').each(function (i, obj) {
            this.innerHTML = TransformedArray[i];
            if (elephantArray[i] <= 70) {
                $(this).parents(".elephant").addClass("walk");
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    var removeNumber = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 21));
    elephantArray[i] = elephantArray[i] - removeNumber;        
}}

var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
timer += 1;
if (timer >= 24) {
    timer = 0
}
document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = timer;
monkeyHealth();
giraffeHealth();
elephantHealth();
}, 2000);
```